# Rails 7 Development on Docker

Tags: docker, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to get a rails 7 app going with bootstrap.  At the end of the dockerfile if I change

```
CMD ["bin/rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

to

> CMD ["./bin/dev"]

or

> CMD ["bin/dev"]

So that foreman spins up css, js, and web processes, I get

[WARNING] Could not load command "rails/commands/server/server_command"

If I run the container with bin/rails it loads and the bootstrap css is there, but the javascript popovers are absent.  Help?

The Procfile.dev is

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
css: yarn build:css --watch
js: yarn build --watch
```

Comment: Can you provide your `gemfile` and also how are you importing Bootstrap? Rails 7 handles JS and CSS to an extent differently than 6 (specifically no more webpacker)